# Filtering with Spring Data Projection

Tags: spring, rest, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, querydsl

I've created a class based Projection for my Spring Data Repository. That works great. Then I tried to annotate the constructor with @QueryProjection from QueryDSL, hoping to get a REST Endpoint with paging, sorting and filtering.

The code looks like this, but there are way more fields and details omitted for brevity:

Entity:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Entity extends BaseEntity {
    private String fieldA, fieldB;
    private AnotherEntity ae;
}
```

DTO:

```
@Getter
@FieldDefaults(makeFinal = true, level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class EntityDto {
    private final String fieldA;
    private final String anotherEntityFieldC;

    @QueryProjection
    public EntityDto(final String fieldA, final String anotherEntityFieldC) {
        this.fieldA = fieldA;
        this.anotherEntityFieldC = anotherEntityFieldC;
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
public EntityRepo extends JpaRepository<Entity, Long>, QuerydslBinderCustomizer<EntityPath<Entity>>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Entity> {
    Page<EntityDto> findPageProjectedBy(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Endpoint:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(EntityEndpoint.ROOT)
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__({@Autowired}))
public EntityEndpoint {
    private final EntityRepo er;

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<PagedResources<Resource<EntityDto>>> getAllEntities(
        Pageable pageable, 
        @QuerydslPredicate(root = EntityDto@.class) Predicate predicate,
        PagedResourcesAssembler<EntityDto> assembler) {
            Page<EntityDto> page = er.findPageProjectedBy(predicate, pageable);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(assembler.toResource(page), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

I get the exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Did not find a static field of the same type in class at.dataphone.logis4.model.dto.QBuchungDto!

[Stacktrace as gist](https://gist.github.com/cptwunderlich/eb7fa9381121d97b20b45b00d102b975)

And that's the URL:

> curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' 'http://localhost:8080/Entity'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems like you can only query with the actual Entity.

I think of it as the part in the 'WHERE'-clause, which can only have columns actually in the selected Entities, while the DTO projection happens in the 'SELECT'-clause.

The `@QueryProjection`-Annotation seems to serve only for the QueryDsl code generator to mark class which then can be used to [create projections in a select-clause](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.0.4/apidocs/com/querydsl/core/annotations/QueryProjection.html)